# Distinguish Supplier from Customer with Exact Online results

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

I have the following query:

```
select act.Division 
,      act.DivisionName
,      act.code
,      act.name
,      act.status
,      acs.description
,      act.IsSupplier
,      act.IsSales
from   exactonlinerest..accounts act
left
outer
join   accountcustomerstatuses acs
on     acs.code = act.status
order
by     Division
,      code
```

Some results give back a status of `C` (customer) and a `true` on `supplier`. `IsSales` is sometimes `true` and sometimes `false`.

I am confused about the meaning of these values. The documentation is not clear on the purpose.

Would that account be both a customer AND a supplier?

What is the meaning of `issales`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer on [documentation](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinerest-crm-accounts.html):

Each counterparty is registered at most once as an account. Their type can be determined using a number of methods:

- Customer: the column 'Status' has the value 'C' when the account is a customer. The meaning of the status codes is described in the table 'AccountStatuses'.
- Prospect: the column 'Status' has the value 'P' when the account is a prospect.
- Suspect: the column 'Status' has the value 'S' when the account is a suspect.
- Reseller: the column 'IsReseller' has the boolean value 'true'.
- Supplier: the column 'IsSupplier' has the boolean value 'true'.
- Accountant: the column 'IsAccountant' has the boolean value 'true'.
- Competitor: the column 'IsCompetitor' has the boolean value 'true'.

Comment: The link isn't working, as it directs to a localhost-file.